# How to use css module in `setup` function?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

Can I refer class name from css module in the setup function of vue3?

```html
<script setup>

console.log(this.$style.myClass) // this won't work

</setup>

<style lang="scss" module>
.myClass {

}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vue-loader` injects the `$style` property (via a `__cssModules` wrapper object) [onto the component instance](https://github.com/vuejs/core/blob/1574edd/packages/runtime-core/src/componentPublicInstance.ts#L338-L343), which can be accessed in `<script setup>` from `getCurrentInstance()`:

```html
<script setup>
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const { $style } = getCurrentInstance().type.__cssModules
console.log('myClass', $style.myClass)
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-access-css-modules-from-script-setup?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

However, use this solution with caution, as `__cssModules` is a private/internal property, which can be renamed or removed in the future without warning.

Comment: Vue now offers `useCssModule` that you can use in setup:

`import { useCssModule } from 'vue';`

`const $style = useCssModule();`

Answer (score 11):

There is a warning in the Vue docs against the use of `getCurrentInstance` (see: https://twitter.com/romainlanz/status/1486279206149492744?s=20)

Vue exposes an api for css modules `useCssModule` for such use cases (see: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#usage-with-composition-api)

```js
<script setup>
import { useCssModule } from 'vue'

const $style = useCssModule()
console.log($style.myClass) // This Works ✅

</setup>

<style lang="scss" module>
.myClass {}
</style>
```

I used the same example above, with both approaches, ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-access-css-modules-from-script-setup-1gfplm?file=src/components/MyComponent.vue)) to show you that the 2 will produce the same thing, just that `useCssModule` is a 'lot safer' to use than `getCurrentInstance`